# Update in Snowflake with CTE

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I cant figure what i am missing in this query , my select is working but not my Update

```
WITH CTE AS
(
select   DATE_key ,ITEM_KEY ,location_key ,
  INVENTORY_AGE ,rank() over ( Partition by Date_key ,ITEM_KEY ,location_key  order by INVENTORY_AGE desc  )  as MIN_AGE , 
ISSUED_QUANTITY,
CYCLE_COUNT_QUANTITY,
PURCHASE_RETURN_QUANTITY,
TRANSFER_QUANTITY
from  "DWH_FACT_INVENTORY"  
where    ISSUED_QUANTITy<>0
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET ISSUED_QUANTITY = 0 
where MIN_AGE <> 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CTE can't be updated. I see you want to update all rows in a table, except one in every (Date_key, ITEM_KEY, location_key) group, though it is not clear to me whether you meant to exclude the newest or oldest row in the group. You name it min_age, but it looks like you are actually looking at the max age. You also don't specify if the min or max INVENTORY_AGE value will be unique for each group. In any case, I hope the following examples give you some idea how to approach this. Try something like:

```
UPDATE DWH_FACT_INVENTORY 
SET ISSUED_QUANTITY = 0 
WHERE ISSUED_QUANTITY <> 0 AND 
      INVENTORY_AGE <> (
                         SELECT MAX(INVENTORY_AGE) 
                         FROM DWH_FACT_INVENTORY mdfi
                         WHERE mdfi.Date_key = DWH_FACT_INVENTORY.Date_key AND
                               mdfi.ITEM_KEY = DWH_FACT_INVENTORY.ITEM_KEY AND
                               mdfi.location_key = DWH_FACT_INVENTORY.location_key
                       )
```

Or something like this:

```
UPDATE DWH_FACT_INVENTORY 
SET ISSUED_QUANTITY = 0 
FROM DWH_FACT_INVENTORY INNER JOIN 
     (
        SELECT Date_key, ITEM_KEY, location_key, MAX(INVENTORY_AGE) AS max_age 
        FROM DWH_FACT_INVENTORY
        GROUP BY Date_key, ITEM_KEY, location_key
     ) mdfi ON mdfi.Date_key = DWH_FACT_INVENTORY.Date_key AND
               mdfi.ITEM_KEY = DWH_FACT_INVENTORY.ITEM_KEY AND
               mdfi.location_key = DWH_FACT_INVENTORY.location_key
WHERE ISSUED_QUANTITY <> 0 AND 
      INVENTORY_AGE <> max_age
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, and yes Age will be unique . However there was requirement to give the data as a view and i just  used  row_number functions and   and displaying the value   `case when row_number() over ( Partition by Inventory.Date_key ,Inventory.ITEM_KEY ,Inventory.location_key  order by Inventory.INVENTORY_AGE desc  )  <>1  THEN 0 ELSE  ISSUED_QUANTITY`

Comment: So you mean to say the purpose was not to update the underlying table, you just wanted to create a view (i.e. a select query) on the table? In that case yes, @jigarshah 's answer is closer to what you want. If it helped you figure out the solution, you can consider marking it as the accepted answer. In any case, it would help to give a little more information about what you are trying to achieve, the next time you post a question on SO.

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of Update Here ? CTE is not actual table. If you just want to do update value you can use that CTE table and use case condition.

Also , you have one extra end bracket ")" in your code.

```
WITH CTE AS (
""" your logic""
)
select DATE_key 
      ,ITEM_KEY
      ,location_key
      ,INVENTORY_AGE
      , case when MIN_AGE <> 1 then  0 
             else ISSUED_QUANTITY 
        as ISSUED_QUANTITY
      ,CYCLE_COUNT_QUANTITY,
      ,PURCHASE_RETURN_QUANTITY,
      ,TRANSFER_QUANTITY
from CTE
```